# VeraCrypt 1.24 Update 7: This distribution package is damaged

Tags: windows-10, setup, veracrypt

I downloaded the current (v1.24-U7) VeraCrypt installer directly from https://www.veracrypt.fr and whenever I try to install it on an "older" offline PC, I get the following error message:

> VeraCrypt Setup
>
> This distribution package is damaged. Please try downloading it again (preferably from the official VeraCrypt website at https://www.veracrypt.fr).

I downloaded it multiple times and I finally also confirmed that the checksums do indeed match. So what can be the reason for this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, it turned out, that my old computer did not have the necessary, current certificates to verify the digitally signed VeraCrypt executables. I had to download and import:

- This root certificate: [GlobalSign Root R3](https://secure.globalsign.net/cacert/Root-R3.crt)
- This intermediate certificate: [GlobalSign Extended Validation Code Signing Intermediate G3](https://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsextendcodesignsha2g3ocsp.crt)

After that, I was able to successfully execute the VeraCrypt executables.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous other certificates needed by VeraCrypt and the installer unfortunately just assumes they are there.

I also added these ones:-
authroot.stl
DigiCert_Assured_ID_MS_Cross_Cert.crt
GlobalSign_Root_CA_MS_Cross_Cert.crt
thawte_Primary_Root_CA.crt

IIRC: the first one was most important for my situation where my User folder had been overwritten with an older version. It is like a library of them available from Microsoft and is updated weekly in the file authrootstl.cab

I won't put links to them - they were easy to find but I don't know that I got them from the best or the official places.

Comment: You don't have to guess which certificates are needed. The veracrypt executables are digitally signed. And from that signature you can exactly determine which certificates you need. For version 1.24 U7, you need exactly the two certificates that I referenced in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1648312/1077440). Besides that, I do not recommend to download certificates from unreliable sources. That will invalidate the whole purpose of certificates.